# How do I get the locale in conversationUpdate activity?

Tags: c#, botframework

I would like to implement a welcome message for every members added based on their locale. The code is as following:

```
if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
{
    // some code...

    if (message.Locale == "en-us")
    {
        var reply = message.CreateReply("Hello world");
    }
    else
    {
        // some code...
    }


    // some code...
}
```

Strangely, the locale is `null` even though I've set the locale both when I test it using bot emulator and [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat). **The locale property is working fine when messages is received.**

Is there any way I could get the locale during conversationUpdate activity?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I made an article on my company's blog on this problem, but it's currently in French. I will add a reply as soon as I can

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution to get the language of the user before his 1st input is to use the `backchannel` feature of the Webchat. This allows us to push information to our bot in a hidden way, to provide locale or a custom id for example.

You will found this demo on GitHub account [here](https://github.com/nrobert/Bot-Language-Demo/).

In particular, here is the sample of integration of your webchat sending the event to the bot at the end with a `postActivity`, created from the samples on Microsoft's Webchat GitHub description:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="bot" />
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Get parameters from query
        const params = BotChat.queryParams(location.search);

        // Language definition
        var chatLocale = params['locale'] || window.navigator.language;

        // Connection settings
        const botConnectionSettings = new BotChat.DirectLine({
            domain: params['domain'],
            secret: 'YOUR_SECRET',
            webSocket: params['webSocket'] && params['webSocket'] === 'true' // defaults to true
        });

        // Webchat init
        BotChat.App({
            botConnection: botConnectionSettings,
            user: { id: 'userid' },
            bot: { id: 'botid' },
            locale: chatLocale,
            resize: 'detect'
        }, document.getElementById('bot'));

        // Send message to provide language of user
        botConnectionSettings.postActivity({
            type: 'event',
            from: { id: 'userid' },
            locale: chatLocale,
            name: 'localeSelectionEvent',
            value: chatLocale
        }).subscribe(function (id) { console.log('event language "' + chatLocale + '" selection sent'); });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I added a console event to show the activity posted.

This event is then received by the bot's `MessageController` and treated:

```
[BotAuthentication]
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// POST: api/Messages
    /// Receive a message from a user and reply to it
    /// </summary>
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        // DEMO PURPOSE: echo all incoming activities
        Activity reply = activity.CreateReply(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(activity, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None));
        var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
        connector.Conversations.SendToConversation(reply);

        // Process each activity
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog());
        }
        // Webchat: getting an "event" activity for our js code
        else if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Event && activity.ChannelId == "webchat")
        {
            var receivedEvent = activity.AsEventActivity();

            if ("localeSelectionEvent".Equals(receivedEvent.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                await EchoLocaleAsync(activity, activity.Locale);
            }
        }
        // Sample for emulator, to debug locales
        else if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate && activity.ChannelId == "emulator")
        {
            foreach (var userAdded in activity.MembersAdded)
            {
                if (userAdded.Id == activity.From.Id)
                {
                    await EchoLocaleAsync(activity, "fr-FR");
                }
            }
        }

        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }

    private async Task EchoLocaleAsync(Activity activity, string inputLocale)
    {
        Activity reply = activity.CreateReply($"User locale is {inputLocale}, you should use this language for further treatment");
        var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
        await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(reply);
    }
}
```

Illustration de l'arrivée des messages :
[image: Exemple messages]

For French speaking users, [here](https://blog.cellenza.com/csharp/bot-framework/bot-framework-webchat-parlez-a-utilisateur-bonne-langue-debut-de-conversation/) is a more detailed answer on my company's blog

Comment: Thanks! I manage to solve this problem as well using the backchannel. Just one question for curiosity: shouldn't the `await EchoLocaleAsync(activity, activity.Locale);` in the `localeSelectionEvent` flow use `activity.Value` instead of `activity.Locale`?

Comment: It may be better yes to be less parameter specific. It's working now as in the postActivity I'm setting the value in both Locale and Value fields

Comment: Ah yes, I just noticed that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

With [DirectLineJs 0.13.0](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS/pull/293), a property has been added that allows to specify the start locale like this:

```
...
createDirectLine({
  token: tokenResponse.token,
  domain: `https://europe.directline.botframework.com/v3/directline`,
  pollingInterval: 500,
  conversationStartProperties: {
    locale : "fr"
  },
  watermark: "-",
})
```

Comment: this really saved me, thanks.