# How to make webchat to send country to bot?

Tags: c#, node.js, location, botframework, web-chat

I want my bot to talk to users on their language, when accessed from a website. This means, that the country(code) should be passed to the bot, but I don't see such option. Is there any way for Webchat to send user's country to bot developed with ms bot framework?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the locale in conversationUpdate activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48296710/how-do-i-get-the-locale-in-conversationupdate-activity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to detect the country code in the controller. I don't think Webchat can automatically detect the users language.

You can use Microsoft Translator API or any other translator to detect the language of the speaker and answer in their language. You can check my translator bot here:
https://github.com/FranciscoPonceGomez/QnATranslatorSample

Microsoft Translator API utilizes a two character country code (EN, ES, FR,...) to know what language has to translate to.
If the accessed website has an option to select the language you could use this information to select the language in the translator.

Comment: It's possible to send information from the site to the bot, it's called Backchannel. See the post I added in the question's comment