# How can I retrieve user locale when a bot or member is added? (MSTeams, conversationUpdate, BotFramework)

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am looking to send the user a localized welcome message from my MSTeams bot, when the user (or the bot itself) is added to a team or chat.
The bot is notified of such events via 'ConversationUpdate' events such as the one shown in the code below.

```
protected override async Task OnTeamsMembersAddedAsync(IList<TeamsChannelAccount> teamsMembersAdded, TeamInfo teamInfo, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var locale = turnContext.Activity.GetLocale(); // This is empty
            // Do stuff based on locale
        }
```

Although the welcome messaging works fine, I am unable to send the message in the user's language, as the IConversationUpdateActivity variable does not contain the 'locale' field.

Does anyone know of a workaround to find the locale of the user who performed the action?

Please note that this is being developed for MSTeams, not for webchat, so the backchannel method mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48296710/how-do-i-get-the-locale-in-conversationupdate-activity) won't work (or is there a way to do this for Teams as well?). Also, I am using
the v4 SDK for .NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

As the bot activity is not initiated by the user action such as sending message. The bot doesn't received any locale information and this is by design and there is no fix for it. Once user sends a message or interact with the bot you can store this information for further interactions.

Also you can have default locale based on the area where application is being used.